# osx: how to make the cmd-tab (application switcher) menu always appear?

Tags: macos

Is it possible (with or without accessory apps) to always show the applications list (menu) appear? Sometimes I feel like I'd be much faster if I knew how many times to press `tab` in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a way for the application switcher to always remain visible on top of other windows, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I meant that, so long as it can be done in a non-obtrusive way. I cycle through several programs and don't remember the order.

Comment: Use Spaces. Lock different apps to different Spaces. Remember the Space numbers. Use key commands to go directly to the Space you need. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme/179403#179403

Comment: Hmm, good answer. Unlike application switcher, the space numbers are fixed, so this is possible.

Comment: I ultimately decided to stop using spaces again. There are other annoyances or things that need to be reconfigured with using spaces. e.g. multiple monitors, time delay from the animation when switching spaces, single window spaces being maximized by default. Provided a better solution with a non-free app in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a non-free solution that seems to do exactly this.

https://contexts.co/

- it has an always visible window manager that numbers windows
- you can switch windows with cmd-#
- you can change the number of the window!

...and a bunch of other things